# Is it possible to create a custom quick settings tile in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have searched the Flutter documentation and googled this, but with zero result. I am developing my first Flutter app for android and I would like to create a custom quick settings tile for it. I am targeting Nougat and above. I know it's possible in Java and Kotlin (e.g. https://android.jlelse.eu/develop-a-custom-tile-with-quick-settings-tile-api-74073e849457), but how about Dart/Flutter?

Comment: I doubt this is supported yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it natively (makes more sense since it is an Android-only feature).

Every Flutter contains an `android` and `ios` folder. Inside of those folders, you will find the wrapper apps for Android and iOS.

Just open the Android project in Android Studio and follow the tutorial you linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Quick setting tile natively

1. Go to android/app/src/main/kotlin/package_name(folder)
2. Create a service class MyTileService.kt

MyTileService.kt

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
//Quick Tile feature can be used Build.VERSION_CODES.N or Greater
class MyTileService : TileService() {

// Called when the user adds your tile.
override fun onTileAdded() {
    super.onTileAdded()
}

// Called when your app can update your tile.
override fun onStartListening() {
    super.onStartListening()

    val tile = qsTile // this is getQsTile() method form java, used in Kotlin as a property
    tile.label = "Set Alarm"
    tile.state = Tile.STATE_ACTIVE
    tile.icon = Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.baseline_alarm_24)

    tile.updateTile() // you need to call this method to apply changes

}
// Called when your app can no longer update your tile.
override fun onStopListening() {
    super.onStopListening()
}

// Called when the user taps on your tile in an active or inactive state.
override fun onClick() {
    super.onClick()
    try{
        // to open flutter activity
        val newIntent= FlutterActivity.withNewEngine().dartEntrypointArgs(listOf("launchFromQuickTile")).build(this)
        newIntent.flags= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivityAndCollapse(newIntent)
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        Log.d("debug","Exception ${e.toString()}")
    }
}

// Called when the user removes your tile.
override fun onTileRemoved() {
    super.onTileRemoved()
}

 }
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
   android:name=".MyTileService"
   android:exported="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/baseline_alarm_24" //your_vector_icon
   android:label="Set Alarm" //tile lable
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
   <intent-filter>
       <action 
android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
   </intent-filter>

  </service>
```

running your app will create a quick setting tile for your app

if not showing -> try to edit the notification panel icons (xiaomi/mi devices)

onClick on this quick settings icon we want to show our flutter screen

Inside main.dart

```
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 runApp(MyApp(
msg: arguments.isNotEmpty ? arguments[0] : null,
 ));
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key, this.msg}) : super(key: key);

final String? msg;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
    initialRoute:  msg == "launchFromQuickTile" ? Create.routeName : 
Home.routeName,
routes: //your routes,
);
}
}
```

[For more information about quick settings tile](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/quicksettings-tiles)

[image]