# How to add a quick settings android tile immediately after app install

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, apk, tile

I'm developing an app and the main use-case is based on the activation/deactivation of its quick settings tile (the swipe down menu buttons).

I don't know how to force the inclusion of the app's tile into the quick settings menu.

The app uses flutter, but some android-specific functionality uses **Kotlin** for its native features.

If it's not possible to **force install** the tile, then I need to include a shortcut or link to it, to make it straightforward (**just like some apps redirect you/show a prompt to change the app's file permissions**, instead of relying on the user changing them manually).

I can't seem to find the way to do this. ([Is it possible to create a custom quick settings tile in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53876203))

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you want

Comment: Like you want to include your app in featured app of your mobile device , than you can’t do this programmatically

Comment: "I don't know how to force the inclusion of the app's tile into the quick settings menu" -- fortunately, that is not possible. "I need to include a shortcut or link to it" -- AFAIK, that too is not possible. Bear in mind that not every Android device *offers* quick settings tiles.

Comment: Hi, check this out.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75522679/14071053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here you can call requestAddTileService() https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/quicksettings-tiles#prompt-user

Comment: That's the Android 13 way. I forgot to specify in my question that I wanted a more general method of doing this. But this is the best answer so far.

Comment: Any code snipped? Just reference to their bare document?