# Quick Settings Tile and Background Dart Code

Tags: flutter, dart, background, background-process

I would like to create a metronome app using Flutter. The app should have a quick settings tile that the user can click on to start playing the metronome beeps without having to open the app. Clicking the tile again should stop the metronome.

I have successfully created the quick settings tile using Kotlin code by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876203/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-quick-settings-tile-in-flutter).

However, I have not been able to find a way to call Dart code from Kotlin without opening the app.

Is this possible?